# Call Function With Multidimensional Array Parameters in Smarty 3 Template Engine

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty, smarty3

The title is quite self explanatory. This is an example of the function I wish to call within my Smarty template without the {php}{/php} tags:

```
form_input(array('name' => 'username', 'id' => 'username', 'value' => set_value('username')))
```

The smarty error I am getting is

```
Unexpected " => ", expected one of: "","" , ")"
```

Comment: How exactly are you trying to call it? Do you mind providing that code?

Answer (score 0):

In case this is what you're using in Smarty, keep in mind that you need to use bracket syntax for arrays (i.e. `{form_input(['name' => 'username', 'id' => 'username', 'value' => {set_value('username')}])}`, or something closer to that)